# Showing completeness of two spaces with a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

*Question:*

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space, $f\colon X\to Y$ a homeomorphism and $c > 0$ a constant so, that $$d'(f(x),f(y)) \le c\cdot d(x,y).$$
Show that also $(Y,d')$ is complete.

*My thoughts:*

For a complete space I know that every Cauchy sequence converges. So I thought I'll take the sequence $(x_n)\in X$ and work forward from the definition of a Cauchy sequence, i.e. $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \,\, \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N} \text{ so that } d(x_n,x_k)<\varepsilon \text{ when } n\ge n_0, k\ge n_0. $$ With this I'd know that $$d'(f(x),f(y)) \le c\cdot d(x,y) \le c\cdot\varepsilon, $$ but then I get stuck. How do I utilise the homeomorphism here, and the convergence requirement? Or is there a better way to approach this?

**Edit:** Might be that I've made a mistake when writing down the problem, and the statement should say that $$d(x,y)\le c\cdot d'(f(x),f(y)).$$ How would you show the completeness of $Y$ with this?

Comment: You need to start with a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, and connect it to some sequence (hopefully Cauchy) in $X$

Comment: Alright, so then I know that $d'(y_n,y_k)<\varepsilon_Y$, and can I say that based on that $d'(f(x_n), f(x_k)) < \varepsilon_Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to show is not true. Take $X = \Bbb R$, $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, $Y = \Bbb R$, $d'(x,y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$.  The identity map is a homeomorphism and $\arctan$ being $1$-Lipschitz, it holds that
$$
\forall x,y \in \Bbb R,\quad |\arctan x - \arctan y | \leqslant |x-y|
$$
so your assumption is true with $c=1$: $d'\leqslant d$. But $(\Bbb R,d)$ is complete while $(\Bbb R, d')$ isn't.

I suspect you made a mistake and should suppose $d \leqslant c d'$, so that a Cauchy sequence for $d'$ would also be a Cauchy sequence for $d$: in that case, this will show that $(Y,d')$ is complete.

Comment: Hmm, this might be the case, as I don't have the original problem at hand... How would you show the other version?

Comment: $d(f^{-1}(x_p),f^{-1}(x_q)) \leqslant cd'(x_p,x_q) \leqslant \varepsilon$ for big enough $p,q\geqslant N$, so that $(f^{-1}(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. It converges. Apply continuity of $f$, so that $(x_n)$ converges as well.